# CKEditor disappears after second ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I'm getting this code via ajax:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#responseContent').ckeditor();
});
</script>
<textarea id='responseContent'></textarea>
```

It successfully generates a CKEditor pane for beautiful text editing.

When this same piece of code is called a second time, I get a blank area.  Oddly, when I do an "inspect element" on where the textarea/ckeditor should be, it says:

```
<textarea id="responseContent" style="visibility: hidden; "></textarea>
```

So, being the professional hack that I am, I jQuery'd it so be visibility:visible.  The CSS stuck but the results didn't look any different.

How do you make ckeditor work... all the time... with ajax generated data?

EDIT:
Just to be clear, I don't believe this is a CSS issue.  I believe it's a jquery/ckeditor issue.

Comment: Are you generating multiple textareas with duplicated IDs?

Comment: Yes but the problem exists when using a classname instead, so it's not a duplicate ID issue.  It seems to be that the ckeditor instance exists and I'm trying to replicate it.  Still unsolved...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found answer here: [CKEditor instance already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794219/ckeditor-instance-already-exists)

```
if(CKEDITOR.instances[editorName]) {
delete CKEDITOR.instances[editorName];
CKEDITOR.replace(editorName);
}
```

One thing that I wasn't sure of (being a ckeditor noob) was the "editorName".  This is the ID of the element that it is created on.  I believe it could be the classname as well, if you used that to create it.

So, in my example in the original question:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('#responseContent').ckeditor();
});
</script>
<textarea id='responseContent'></textarea>
```

I would fix it like this:

```
if(CKEDITOR.instances["responseContent"]) {
    delete CKEDITOR.instances["responseContent"];
    // I replaced this step
    // CKEDITOR.replace("responseContent");
    // With this:
    $('#responseContent').ckeditor();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the `$('#responseContent').ckeditor();` line be outside the `if` statement ? or why to call the `ckeditor()` method twice?

Comment: Hi your answer is useful to me . Thanks for that . But one thing also need to do it that I had to add Jquery.js file from ckeditor/adapters that <script src="~/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script> . I can't understand this behaviour . If you know anything than let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This script can help you with ajax loaded textareas with '.ckeditor' class:

```
$('#edytuj_promocje').load('your_php_file_with_ckeditor_textarea.php', function(){

   $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(){
     eval("CKEDITOR.instances."+this.name+".destroy(true)");
   });
   $('.ckeditor').each( function(){ 
    CKEDITOR.replace(this);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're trying to populate the same instance of ckeditor with different content, correct?

If so, then there are other methods to change that content. Trying to create an additional instance will cause you problems.

http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery

Scroll down to 'Code interaction with editor instances'

Comment: Yes, I am.  I can see where that "editor instances" is going, but the documentation seems to be quite skimpy.  It seems that I need to check for an instance, if it exists then use it.  How do I write that code?

Comment: Try $('#responseContent').val('some new html content');

Comment: That just writes text into the editor.  I'm trying to get the actual instance of the editor.

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794219/ckeditor-instance-already-exists            if(CKEDITOR.instances[editorName])
   delete CKEDITOR.instances[editorName];
CKEDITOR.replace(editorName);

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is like this:

```
jQuery.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(){
     eval("CKEDITOR.instances."+this.name+".destroy(true)");
});
```

Comment: eval? you must be kidding me.