# ckeditor initizialize and destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I know there are similar question on stackoverflow or google, but nothing helps so far..
I use ckeditor with jquery adapter in leatest stable version.

After clicking back and forward i got following error in firebug:

```
uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "cause" already exists
```

when i now try to destroy the editor by:

```
var editor=jQuery("#cause").ckeditorGet();
editor.destroy();
```

i got following error:

```
CKEditor not yet initialized, use ckeditor() with callback.
```

If i try to reproduce the issue step by step (except the back/forward button)
i got some different behavior in firebug

create a new ckeditor

```
jQuery('#cause').ckeditor();
```

destroy the editor again

```
var editor=jQuery('#cause').ckeditorGet();
editor.destroy();
```

try to recreate the editor fails (without any warning or error)

```
jQuery('#cause').ckeditor();
```

result:
the textarea stays

expected result:
the editor come up again

any help would be appreciated

Comment: hmm for some strange reasons i cannot reproduce my problem anymore...  yust want let you know that delete CKEDITOR.instances.cause; fixed my issue

Comment: related post to any others who come here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794219/ckeditor-instance-already-exists

Comment: You can check a live example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902441/how-to-destroy-and-reinitialize-ckeditor-again/48902974#48902974

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that it crashes if it has not already been initialised before hand. However this works.

Destroy the instance. (assuming that you have a global called CKEDITOR.

```
if(CKEDITOR){
    if(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1){
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I call this using jquery adapter?