# How to Destroy and Reinitialize CKEDITOR Again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I use the below code to destroy the editor instance.

```
editor.destroy();
```

After this, I try to initialize CKEditor and set content using the below code.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData("MY HTML DATA");
```

But when I am doing like this only the empty HTML page is Shown.

[image: Empty page]

How can I do this in a Correct Way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ckeditor initizialize and destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925094/ckeditor-initizialize-and-destroy)

Comment: destroy will work.Initialization will not

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, following fiddle will help you in initializing and destroying ckeditor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div name="editor1">TEST CONTENT</div>
    <button id="toogleEditor">
    TOOGLE EDITOR
    </button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the JS

```
var editorInstance;
     document.getElementById('toogleEditor').addEventListener('click',function() {
      if (CKEDITOR) {
        if (editorInstance) {
            editorInstance.destroy();
          editorInstance = undefined;
        } else {
          editorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
          editorInstance.setData("MY HTML DATA");
        }
      }
    })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samuelj90/0hx0bnk9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Operations you have described require time to complete thus please use events to control when editor gets created and destroyed:

- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-instanceReady
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#event-instanceDestroyed

  ```
      var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
          language: 'en'
      });

      // Recreate editor after it has been destroyed
      CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceDestroyed', function() {
          CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
      } );

      // Set editor data after it has been created
      CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
          evt.editor.setData("MY HTML DATA");
      } );
  ```