# remove CKeditor instance if it's already exists in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

how can I remove CKeditor instance if it's already exists with jQuery help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:
`CKEDITOR.instances.*instanceName*.destroy();`

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy

To remove an editor after checking it exists:
[CKEditor instance already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794219/ckeditor-instance-already-exists)

Comment: I know that, but how can I find out if instance exist?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a link you might find relevant.
`if(CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName)` will check if an instance exists. I doubt you need to use JQuery for this task.