# jquery adapter and ckeditor issue

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I am doing some php programming with jquery adapter and ckeditor on my page. Let me show what I have. The page I am working on is index.php

A jquery adapter:

```
    function sendid(id)
     {
    jQuery('#mydiv').showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: id,
        error: function(){

          alert('error');
      },
      success: function(data){
        jQuery('#mydiv').hideLoading();
            $('#mydiv').html(data);
  }
  });
}
}
```

This function sends an id to index.php . Whith this Id I am fetching my database and get some records. With the record I got, I am displaying it via ckeditor like this:

```
          <?php
            $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
            $ckeditor->basePath  = 'ckeditor/' ;
            CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor, 'ckfinder/' ) ;
            $config['height'] = '300';
            $initialValue = $queryresult['content'];
            $ckeditor->editor('FCKeditor1', $initialValue, $config);
        ?>
```

Whenever I click the button which calls sendid() function ckeditor appears above the list of ids. The first time when I call sendid() function it works ok and puts the record into ckeditor. However second time I call the sendid() function ckeditor disappears.

I found a topic in this link:

[CKEditor instance already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794219/ckeditor-instance-already-exists)

but it becomes very hard for me, where to place the codes mentioned in the link. As far as I understood I have to kill or destroy the editor everytime I click the button for sending the id to sendid() function. But whenever I put destroy or kill ckeditor into sendid() function it did not work.

Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, download the latest CKEditor from http://ckeditor.com/download. Unpack it on your server so you can run it, for example `http://localhost/ckeditor_test/` (anywhere you like).

Now, save the following code in the same directory where all the editor files have been unpacked (`ckeditor.js`, `ckeditor_php5.php` and so on) as `index.php`.

Open the webiste and enjoy clicking the button. This sample (sandbox, actually) will let you understand how to replace an editor dynamically and destroy existing instances to avoid conflicts.

```
<?php if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] === 'POST' ): ?>
    <?php
        include( 'ckeditor_php5.php' );

        $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
        $ckeditor->editor( $_POST[ 'id' ], 'This is my initial value!', array(
            'height' => '300'   // Config to be used
        ));
    ?>
<?php else: ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" style="outline: 2px dashed orange; padding: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px;">
            This is where the editor will be loaded.
        </div>
        <button id="load" type="submit">Load the editor via AJAX!</button>
        <script>

            (function( $ ) {
                var id = 'idOfTheEditor';

                $( '#load' ).on( 'click', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'index.php',
                        data: {
                            id: id
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            console.log( 'Error?' );
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            if ( window.CKEDITOR && CKEDITOR.instances[ id ] ) {
                                console.log( 'Desytroying an existing instance!' );
                                CKEDITOR.instances[ id ].destroy();
                            }
                            $( '#mydiv' ).html( data );
                        }
                    });
                });

            })( jQuery );

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php endif ?>
```

You can eventually wrap `$( '#mydiv' ).html( data )` in `setTimeout` closure like this to see your code working in "slow motion":

```
setTimeout( function() {
        $( '#mydiv' ).html( data );
}, 1000 );
```

Have fun!

Comment: oleq thank you so much,it worked. what I did is based on what you sent me, I modified the jquery adapter like:  function sendid(id)
     {
    jQuery('#mydiv').showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: "id="+id,
        error: function(){

          alert('error');
      },
      success: function(data){
        jQuery('#mydiv').hideLoading();
        if ( window.CKEDITOR && CKEDITOR.instances[ id ] ) {
             CKEDITOR.instances[ id ].destroy();                                                                $('#mydiv').html(data);
  }
  });
}
}

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure your id is passed properly. Also `jQuery === $`, so `('#mydiv')` can be `$('#mydiv')` if you don't use any other libraries which could overwrite `$` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your jQuery code should look like this for the patch to work:

```
function sendid(id)
     {
    jQuery('#mydiv').showLoading();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: id,
        error: function(){

          alert('error');
      },
      success: function(data){
        jQuery('#mydiv').hideLoading();

        var instance = CKEDITOR.instances['FCKeditor1'];
        if(instance) {
            instance.destroy(true);
        }
        CKEDITOR.replace('FCKeditor1');

        $('#mydiv').html(data);
  }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Zathrus, Thank you so much for your reply. I tried it and this time even in the first time ckeditor did not appear.

Comment: so you don't have a CKEditor on the page before you click the button for the first time at all?

Comment: First I just have list of ids and I click the one that I want to modify. #mydiv, in which there is a CKEditor, appears in the same page.

Comment: could you update your question with a sample HTML code? I'm not quite sure I understand now :)

Comment: Hey zathrus I tried to post some code but stackoverflow did not let me to answer for 5 hours. Is there any way that I can send you the code?

Comment: there you go Zathrus, I uploaded it as an image and here is the [link](http://b1209.hizliresim.com/11/l/d55wf.png)

Comment: there is a </div> tag at the end of the document. I forgot to write it.

Comment: Zathrus above post of oleq fixed my problem

Comment: sry, I didn't have time to reply... glad it solved your problem :)